# Как при открытии приложения открывать ссылку в браузере?

Tags: android

Никогда раньше не писал под андроид и первый раз в жизни сел за Android Studio.
Поставили передо мной задачу, написать приложение на андроиде, при открытии которого должен открываться браузер и переходил на сайт.

Я знаю (по видеоурокам на ютюбе), что можно это реализовать при нажатии на кнопку в приложении. Но можно ли сделать это без этой кнопки, что бы запустил приложение и сразу перешло на сайт.

Подскажите, как лучше всего это будет сделать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Я немного отредактировал вопрос. APK - не приложение, а пакет для установки (Android Package Kit). При "запуске" apk запускается не приложение из этого apk, а сам APK открывается службой установки приложений и приложение устанавливается. И только после этого его можно запустить.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы Ваше приложение при запуске сразу же закрылось и запустило любимый браузер пользователя и в нём нужный Вам сайт? Или же показать сайт в самом приложении (на это ответ уже дан)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации Вашей задачи достаточно использовать WebView, примеры использования можно посмотреть на [официально сайте](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview).

Чтоб осуществить переход по ссылке без нажатия на кнопку - можно использовать к приеру жизненный цикл активити - в методе `onCreate` задать ссылку для открытия.

Пример:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно открыть страницу в приложении, см. ответ @Vitaly Tomashevsky. Если нужно, чтобы открылся браузер и страница открылась в нем, то можно сделать так:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";    
Intent openPage= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(openPage);
```

И положить этот код тоже в `onCreate()` или куда вам хочется.